# VBA EXCEL Search for matches in a string of text in a column vs a different column on a different sheet. If match found, Copy & Paste

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying desperately to learn Excel well enough to do this on my own but I can't figure this out. I really appreciate any help you can give me. I posted before with not nearly enough information, so this is the repost with more info.

A document is pasted in cell A9.

It fills every cell below it with lines of data, up to A200.

The lines of data look like this:

```
192800002001 19280 G RG474 56 DAY PMI COMPLETE
19280A001001 19280 G CB359 AN/PRC-152A 56 DAY PMI
19280A005001 19280 G CB360 AN/PRC-152A 56 DAY PMI
```

I need the program to search each cell in column A for the words that look like "RG474" or "CB359" and search in a reference table on a different sheet in the same book. The table on the reference table looks like this

```
RG474 | xxx474 0 | 0 | IN RACK | AF6
CB915 | xxx359 0 | 0 | IN RACK | AF6
```

For every match found it pastes the row from the reference table into the row of the match next to the pasted document (columns L-Q).

I've found some code online that I've tried to no avail, the two things I tried are here:

```vb
    Dim lastRw1, lastRw2, nxtRw, m

    'Determine last row with data, refrene
    lastRw1 = Sheets("380 Refrence").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Determine last row with data, Import
    lastRw2 = Sheets("analyser").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Loop through Import, Column A
    For nxtRw = 9 To lastRw2
        'Search Sheet1 Column C for value from Import
        With Sheets("380 Refrence").Range("A9:A" & lastRw1)
            Set m = .Find(Sheets("analyser").Range("A" & nxtRw), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            'Copy Import row if match is found
            If Not m Is Nothing Then
                Sheets("analyser").Range("A" & nxtRw & ":F" & nxtRw).Copy _
                Destination:=Sheets("380 Refrence").Range("L" & m.Row)
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Sub CopyImportData()

    Dim lastRw1, lastRw2, nxtRw, m
    Dim code As String, RefRow As Integer
    Dim rowValues

    'Determine last row with data, 380 Refrencerene
    lastRw1 = Sheets("380 Refrence").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Determine last row with data, Import
    lastRw2 = Sheets("analyser").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Row = 9 To lastRw2
        With Sheets("analyser").Cell(Row, 1)
            'meet the laziest error handling ever to find your 380 Refrenceerence value
            code = WorksheetFunction.Mid(.Value, WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.Search("CB??? ", .Value), WorksheetFunction.Search("RG??? ", .Value)), 1), 5)
        End With

        With Sheets("380 Refrence")
            'Use Excel Match to find the 380 Refrenceerence row, which is offset by 8
            'I swear I'll stop using iferror
    380         RefrenceRow = WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.Match(code, .Range("A9:A" & lastRw1), 0) + 8, -1)

            '-1 is our safeword, copy the range
            If RefRow <> -1 Then
                .Range("A" & RefRow & ":F" & RefRow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("analyser").Range("L" & Row)
            End If
        End With
    Next Row
End Sub
```

I didn't write either of these and don't fully understand them, but I do get the Gist of it.

Here's a *very* trimmed down duplicate of the workbook: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qCz8DUCz6tA5-KbxKDnvRq_KiBDkl4W5

Comment: Is it always exactly the text "RG" or "CB" followed by 3 digits?

Comment: There are several identifiers, not just RG or CB, but it is always followed by three charachters. Sometimes the first number is a letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me - I skipped some of the "find last cell" bits so you'll need to adjust for that

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim c As Range, v, f
    Dim ws380 As Worksheet, wsAn As Worksheet

    Set ws380 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("380 Reference")
    Set wsAn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("analyser")

    For Each c In wsAn.Range("A1:A50") 'for example
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            v = GetMatch(c.Value)
            Debug.Print c.Address, v

            If Len(v) > 0 Then
                'got a value - look it up...
                Set f = ws380.Range("A9:A5000").Find(v, lookat:=xlWhole, _
                                                    lookin:=xlValues)
                If Not f Is Nothing Then
                    f.Resize(1, 6).Copy c.EntireRow.Cells(1, "L") 'copy found row
                End If
            End If

        End If
    Next c

End Sub


Function GetMatch(txt As String)

    Dim re As Object, allMatches, m

    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    'looking for two upper-case letters then 3 digits, or 3 letters plus 2 digits
    ' with a word boundary on each end
    re.Pattern = "(\b([A-Z]{2}\d{3}\b)|(\b[A-Z]{3}\d{2})\b)"
    re.ignorecase = False
    re.Global = True

    Set allMatches = re.Execute(txt)
    For Each m In allMatches
        GetMatch = m.Value
        Exit For
    Next m

End Function
```

Here's a good vbscript regexp reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ms974570(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. It runs with no errors but unfortunately it does not seem to do anything.

In cell A of the analyser sheet is this whole string "19280A021001   19280 G  CB374 AN/PRC-152A 56 DAY PMI"

In case that could be an issue

Comment: Another issue that may be a problem, The sheet "380 Reference" Pulls it's data from a different worksheet with a formula in each cell similar to "='PRC'!D4"

If it would be easier to do this in Access or something and just pull the info from the worksheets on excell I could do that aswell but i've got only a little bit of experience with Access

Comment: Here's a working version: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xd4WS-ZM8HvLg9aXJpnpLXf7Kupi2wjy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you very much! If you wanna email me at robdoc@live.com I'll send you a reward. I appreciate the work.

Comment: Thanks for the offer but I'm good thanks - just here for practice...